# Calling an instance method in a Rails 3 model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, csv

I started reading Rails Antipatterns today and I wanted to put some of those practices into action. I'm refactoring a CSV export that I had originally built in a controller. Since this is a bad practice, I factored it out into the model... then its own model. This way I can reuse the method for other purposes.

I have a model with the following method:

```
#app/models/imagery_request.rb
class ImageryRequest < ActiveRecord::Base

def convert
    ImageryRequestConverter.new(self)
  end

end
```

I have another model like this:

```
#app/models/imagery_request_converter.rb
class ImageryRequestConverter
  attr_reader :imagery_requests

  def initialize(imagery_requests)
    @imagery_requests = imagery_requests
  end

  def to_csv
    csv_string = FasterCSV.generate do |csv|
      # header row
      csv << ["id", "service_name", "description", "first_name", "last_name", "email", "phone_contact", "region",
        "imagery_type", "file_type", "pixel_type", "total_images",
        "tile_size", "progress", "expected_date", "high_priority", "priority_justification",
        "raw_data_location", "service_overviews", "is_def",
        "isc_def", "special_instructions", "navigational_path", "FY Queue",
        "created_at", "updated_at"]
      # data rows
      @imagery_requests.each do |ir|
        csv << [ir.id, ir.service_name, ir.description, ir.first_name, ir.last_name, ir.email,
          ir.phone_contact, ir.region, ir.imagery_type, ir.file_type, ir.pixel_type,
          ir.total_images, ir.tile_size, ir.progress, ir.expected_date, ir.high_priority,
          ir.priority_justification, ir.raw_data_location, ir.service_overviews,
          ir.is_def, ir.isc_def, ir.special_instructions, ir.navigational_path,
          ir.fyqueue, ir.created_at, ir.updated_at
        ]
      end
      # send it to the browser with proper headers
      send_data csv_string,
        :type => 'text/csv; charset=iso-8859-1; header=present',
        :disposition => "attachment; filename=Imagery_Requests-#{Time.now.strftime("%Y%m%d")}.csv"
    end
  end
end
```

When I try to reference this in my view with:

```
<%= link_to @imagery_requests.convert.to_csv %>
```

I get an error:

```
undefined method `convert' for #<ActiveRecord::Relation:0x21f966d0>
```

How do I call this method?

Answer (score 0):

The `@imagery_requests` variable is actually a `Relation` object which will always be a collection of records once its called. You're calling an instance method on this object, which won't work because you calling it on the *whole* collection and not an object inside this collection.

Besides that, calling the method in a `link_to` like you're doing there just won't work full-stop. The link should go to a controller action which parses these requests and returns the CSV correctly.

Comment: So I basically have to put all that CSV creation code in a controller action? There's got to be a more elegant/reusable way.

Answer (score 0):

**Follow-on to Ryan Bigg's answer**

You have two issues:

1. To call the convert method, you need to specify an object within the collection. Eg. `@imagery_requests.first.convert.to_csv` or `@imagery_requests[i].convert.to_csv` etc.
2. You can't have a link to the contents of a file, which is what your code is trying to do. Instead, you need to link to a new action, eg download_csv that will return the csv.

Since the new action (download a csv version of the file) is not part of the standard restful suite, you'll need to add *additional actions* to the resource. [Eg article](http://markconnell.co.uk/posts/2010/02/rails-3-routing-examples)

**User experience (UX) choices:**
You could create a download as csv action for each *member* of the `ImageryRequests`  collection, this would mean that a person who wants the csv version for 5 requests would need to download the 5 different csv files.

Or you could create a download for the *collection.* But each http request has one response. The usual solution: return a zip file to the client with the multiple files.

In any case, you're right that you should move the code into a model and out of the controller.

**EMail UX solution** This one is especially good if it would take more than a split second to create the csv files--since Rails is single threaded, all responses should be very quick.

Instead of responding with a file, the form for the csv download should take an email address as a parameter. Then use DelayJob or other scheduler to send out the csv files via email in the background.

You can send the zip file as the email attachment or send the multiple csv files since an email can have multiple attachments.

A tip: your form should handle multiple email addresses and enable the user to include a cover note in the email. This will enable requestors to send the report to multiple people.

Comment: Right, I understand the View issue regarding link_to. As far as my UX choices, I'd like all rows to be returned in one CSV. In the future, I'll have an advanced search that'll return a CSV based on a date range.